# Searching through an array and returning a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need your help,

Id' like to be able to come up with a javascript function that is similar to the following code structure below, except for the fact that I am not that strong enough in programming to come up with a workable solution to work from.

I'd like to be able to input a given value, then, using that value, search through an array and return the value short name (the value on the right side of the : colon character)

```
function test() {

var filenames = [
        "REQUEST FOR INFO":"REQI",
        "MEDIA CALL":"MC",
        "ISSUES NOTE":"ISN"
    ]

EX1.)

    var value_to_search_for = "REQUEST FOR INFO (ALPHA)"

    if (value_to_search_for matches the value in the array filenames) then {

        return "REQI"

    }

EX.2)
    var value_to_search_for = "MEDIA CALL"

    if (value_to_search_for matches value in the array filenames) then {

        return "MC"

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know objects?

Comment: it looks like an object with properties. if it should be an array, it is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change that to object and then you can do this

```js
var filenames = {
  "REQUEST FOR INFO": "REQI",
  "MEDIA CALL": "MC",
  "ISSUES NOTE": "ISN"
};

var getValue = function(val, obj) {
  if (val in obj) return obj[val];
}

console.log(getValue('ISSUES NOTE', filenames));
```

You can also change that to array of objects and then you can do this

```js
var filenames = [
  {"REQUEST FOR INFO": "REQI"},
  {"MEDIA CALL": "MC"},
  {"ISSUES NOTE": "ISN"}
];

var getValue = function(val, array) {
  array.forEach(function(el) {
    for (prop in el) {
      if (prop == val) console.log(el[prop]);
    }
  });
}

getValue('MEDIA CALL', filenames);
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad, this code works great if there is no value in backets at the end of my string but if there is, alert(getValue('REQUEST FOR INFO (ABC)', filenames)); comes up as undefined. I like where you are going with this though. Very appreciative of the effort that has gone into this so far :)

Comment: You're welcome. You need exact match here or values won't match. But this is how you can iterate through this data structure.